# Is there any algorithm to make round robin schedule having each round unique combinations?

Tags: php, algorithm, fixtures

Suppose I have an array of 10 participants [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Assuming a league, as there are 10 participants, so each participant will have 9 matches with other 9 participants.

Therefore, there will be 9 rounds having single matches for each participant. For example-

Round 1: 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-10 [no repeat for any participant]

Round 2: 1-3, 2-4, 5-7, 8-9, 6-10 [no repeat for any participant]

and so on..

Is there any mathematical algorithmic solution/pattern there?

I would like to avoid array push/pop method if possible.

Comment: `Round robin scheduling` isn't a very good title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is rather simple algorithm  to generate all possible pairs (`(N-1)*N/2`)
Put items into two rows.
At every round player from the top row plays with corresponding player from bottom row.
Fix the first one.
Shift all others in cyclic manner.

Note that you can work with indexes of array, not changing it's contents

```
A  B
D  C
pairs A-D, B-C

A  D
C  B
pairs A-C, D-B

A  C
B  D
pairs A-B, C-D
```

My naive implementation in PHP ([ideone](https://ideone.com/L54q54)) outputs indexes of players:

```
function GenPairs($N) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$N-1;$i++){
        echo(0).":";
        echo($N - 1 - $i)."\n";
        for ($j=1; $j<$N/2;$j++){
            echo(1 + (($N - $i + $j - 2) % ($N - 1))).":";
            echo(1 + ((2*$N - $i - $j - 3) % ($N - 1)))."\n";
        }
            echo("\n");
    }
}    


GenPairs(6);

0:5
1:4
2:3

0:4
5:3
1:2

0:3
4:2
5:1

0:2
3:1
4:5

0:1
2:5
3:4
```

Comment: Why don't you give a proper example instead of just saying what the code should do?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Because I am not good in PHP, don't sure what data structures are better, so only describe algorithm

Comment: Can you please show what the OP requested? (Nine rounds, each with five pairs and no repeat matches.)

Comment: @גלעד ברקן  Yes, it is possible to change 6 to 10 in ideone and get 9 rounds each with 5 pairs, no repeats: [link](https://ideone.com/0GIbSV)

Comment: That's a good solution. But now I'm thinking of odd number of players..  :)

Comment: @Fahim Iqbal One player must have the rest every round. My Python implementation works fine for odd number - it uses integer division, while PHP version makes extra output where resting player plays with himself. To remove, it is needed to change line `for ($j=1; $j<($N-1)/2;$j++)`

Comment: Can you extend this question with 9 unique games in stead of 9 matches and making sure that every player has played each unique game once? (Think of decathlon but with nine games)

Comment: @KjVdB If you mean that players A,B,C... should play games 1,2,3... then it is sufficient to cyclically rotate players after every round. A B C D then B C D A then C D A B then D A B C