# Create array from non repetitive combination (pair of two) of elements such that in each set all elements occur only once

Tags: algorithm, loops, multidimensional-array, data-structures, pseudocode

Assume I have this array:

`[A,B,C,D,E,F]`

I want to create this output:

`[[AB,CD,EF],[AC,BE,DF],[AD,BF,CE],[AE,BD,CF],[AF,BC,DE]]`
where in each set we have all elements occurring only once.

I have already generated unique pairs of elements - `[AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,BC,BD,BE,BF,CD,CE,CF,DE,DF,EF]`.

I need pseudo code for this problem.

Comment: You're effectively generating all possible pairings. Common problem with multiple solutions on the web

Comment: [round-robin schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730923/is-there-any-algorithm-to-make-round-robin-schedule-having-each-round-unique-com/56730988#56730988)